# Sitecore SXA Preview Item error

Tags: sxa

I am using sitecore 9.3 with SXA and i faced an issue while trying to preview an item but i am not sure what can be the root cause of this it happens appears several times, any one has faced this issue before?

```
10292 11:29:41 ERROR Application error. Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. Source: System.Web    at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Source: mscorlib    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)    at Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args, Pipeline pipeline)    at Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(PipelineArgs args, Boolean atomic)   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.RunPipelines()    at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)    at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)    at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.NullReferenceException Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Source: Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing    at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing.Commands.PreviewItem.RunPreview(ClientPipelineArgs args, Item item)
```

also other time i faced the below error

```
11004 11:32:49 ERROR Failed to render rendering
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: An unhandled exception occurred.
Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.ExecuteController(Controller controller)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.Execute(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.XA.Feature.SiteMetadata
   at Sitecore.XA.Feature.SiteMetadata.Services.ExternalLinkGenerator.GetExternalUrl(Item item)
   at Sitecore.XA.Feature.SiteMetadata.Repositories.OpenGraphMetadata.OpenGraphMetadataRepository.GetMetaTags()
   at Sitecore.XA.Feature.SiteMetadata.Repositories.MetadataBaseRepository`1.GetModel()
   at Sitecore.XA.Feature.SiteMetadata.Controllers.OpenGraphMetadataController.GetModel()
   at Sitecore.XA.Feature.SiteMetadata.Controllers.MetadataController.Index()
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

Please advise if you have any idea how to troubleshoot this to investigate the issue more.

Comment: Hi @Nali, did you find any solution for this? I had to restart IIS Website to make this work, but it seems an issue with SXA

Comment: yes it seems this an issue with SXA, for me it is fixed when you open the SXA site manger and publish site

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue happened to us in `Sitecore 10.0 SXA` instance whenever a site is created newly.

A solution that worked for me is :

1. Go to `Powershell toolbox` in the content editor - start menu
2. Click on `SXA Site manager`

[image]

3. Search for your site in search box

[image]

4. Click on the `Publish option` and `publish` your site

[image]
5) Check to preview your item now

Hope this helps!!